# Error trying to make a discord selfbot in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I'm trying to make a discord selfbot in python and I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tauga\Documents\luna.py", line 4, in <module>
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="*", self_bot=True, help_command=False)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

I have tried rewriting the code many times and nothing has worked

My code

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="*", self_bot=True, help_command=False)
token="my discord token that i'm not showing"

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Luna Online")

@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("luna Test Command")

client.run(token, bot=False)
```

If anyone could help that would be great!

Comment: Self bots are against discord terms of service and can get your account banned.

Comment: I am aware but I would still like to fix it

Answer (score 1):

It's actually because selfbots are not supported by Discord.py anymore since it's agains TOS. You could re-install a previous version of Discord.py to create a selfbot. The last version that supported selfbots was 1.7.3, you can install it using `pip install discord==1.7.3`, `pip install discord-py==1.7.3`

Answer (score 0):

Try this `client= commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())`

Your error was because discord api requires intents, which you never set.

To run the bot use `client.run("token", bot=False)`

And for the command, use `ctx.channel.send("test message here")`

Please note, self botting is a very bad idea, and will likely result in getting banned.

Comment: make sure to upvote!

Comment: Don't help people to break TOS. Besides, this error is really simple & self-explanatory (and has been asked a thousand times) so if they really want to break TOS they should be able to figure it out themselves.

Comment: hey, if they want to break TOS and get banned, making them want to abuse the api less and less over time, who am I to deny the knowledge that leads to that?

Comment: Lol I was just curios on how selfbots work geez.

Comment: lol, nothing wrong with being curious, but I don't need some stranger telling me what I'm not allowed to do...because then i turn into a smarta**